image using file path does not load in Typescript
I have a reducer.ts file, path is: src/model/reducer/reducer.ts
and the path for my image is: src/view/assets/image.png
Here is how I work with my image inside my reducer:
const myImage = '../../view/assets/image.png'
if (condition) {
   state.logoImg = myImage
}

With that piece of code, my image is not loaded, it shows like this instead:

How can I fix this error?
Thank you so much in advance!

Relative URLs get resolved against the URL of the document you embedded the script into, not against the URL of the script itself.

Import your image..
import myImage from '../../view/assets/image.png';
Then you can use it like this:
logoImg: myImage,

Hi Salt, I tried import before and got the error: "Cannot find module  '../../view/assets/image.png' or its corresponding type declarations.

is this react? are you using weback?

Yes, I’m using webpack
